By placing a GoogleMap in a stack with a list, by scrolling the list GoogleMap also moves

In a stack I inserted a GoogleMap in the background and a card containing a list in the foreground. Trying to scroll the list, it scrolls but the map also moves. How is it possible to get around this problem?
Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AsyncValueWidget(
            value: mapDataAsync,
            data: (mapData) => FlyZoneMapWidget(
              flyZones: mapData.flyZones,
              position: mapData.position,
              mapStyle: mapData.mapStyle,
              onZonesSelected: (flyZones) {
                if (flyZones.isNotEmpty) {
                  ref.read(selectedZoneProvider.notifier).state =
                      flyZones.first;
                } else {
                  ref.read(selectedZoneProvider.notifier).state = null;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          const MapControllerLayer()
        ],
      ),
    );

